# sfDoctrineGuardPlugin: login with email

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine

I'm building a webapp with symgony1.4 and doctrine1.2, and I wanna use the sfDoctrineGuardPlugin, but I have a little problem.

sfDoctrineGuardPlugin is built to authenticate by username, but I need to change it to ask for an email.

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: It should be simple enough. Start with a search through the plugin for 'username', and start replacing :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://bluehorn.co.nz/2009/06/12/symfony-12-propel-and-sfguardplugin-email-login/

This has been written for propel, but probably is easily applicable with doctrine.

Comment: I did something more or less like that

Answer (score 6):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you want to allow login with e-mail.

sfDoctrineGuardPlugin supports login using e-mail or username, but in version 5.0.0 is broken, according to this ticket:

http://trac.symfony-project.org/ticket/8919

There is a patch there. Apply the patch and create an entry in your app.yml setting allow_login_with_email to true:

```
all:
  sf_guard_plugin:
    allow_login_with_email: true
```

Is this what you need?

Comment: This doesn't seem to actually work, or, you need this plus a manual change in one of the validator classes to use retrieveByUsernameOrEmailAddress() instead of retrieveByUsername(). Strange, not your answer but Symfony.

Answer (score 4):

How about keeping sfDoctrineGuard as it is, using the existing username field, but saving emails into it. Your users would then login with their emails. The default field length is VARCHAR(128) which is plenty for any email. If I remember right, the only thing you'd need to tweak is the form label for sfguard signup, signin, etc (wherever you display it). You'd basically just say "Enter email here" instead of saying "Enter username here".

The only downside is that you lose the "username", but you could always put that in a separate profile that's related to sfGuardUser.

If you don't like that approach, you can always tweak the sfDoctrineGuardPlugin code directly, but it's probably going to cause some headache.

Comment: Validations would be wrong, and names would be also wrong all over the code... I prefer not to do that.

Comment: Your downvote isn't justified. You can override the validation very easily by adding custom validation on top. And you never specified you wanted to keep usernames intact.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to answer this in case someone else read this question looking for help.

As oznek pointed out, you have to use the "allow_login_with_email" parameter.

However, there's a bug in the plugin (at least in version 5.0.0) that prevents it from working.
You have to modify this file: `/sfDoctrineGuardPlugin/lib/validator/sfGuardValidatorUser.class.php`
line 44
replace this:

```
$user = $this->getTable()->retrieveByUsername($username);
```

with this:

```
$user = $this->getTable()->$method($username);
```

(the "`$method`" variable is defined a few lines above, but never used)